# How to use a script to start another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, Im pretty new to unity, and c#, and Im trying to make a system where I can attach a script to an object in unity, and then assign a certain script to this object, so when the player interacts with it, it will call a script. so...

here is where i need to be able to put a script:

[image: here is where i need to be able to put a script]

and

here is what I have currently:

[image: here is what I have currently]

Comment: It wont let me put unity 2d in the tags. but yeah its not unity 3d.

Comment: please post code as text rather than screenshots

Comment: Your code and Inspector screenshot don't match ... if `Action` is of type `ScriptableObject` then you first need to [create an **instance**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you want(I think what you want is bad practise or unachievable), but you can obtain same functionality via following steps,

First you need to create prefab which your script attached to it. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wS5f0OKucxM) is small tutorial for that. Then you can use following code.

```
public GameObject myPrefab;

// This script will simply instantiate the Prefab when the game starts.
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("f")){
    // Instantiate at position (0, 0, 0) and zero rotation.
        Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i could use more detail, I'm not really sure what you're saying. The only reason i was thinking of this problem specifically like this is because i could then use this script on any object that is interactable, so i could put it on any interactable object and then assign it the script that handles what it does.

Comment: I edited the comment now it should be more explanatory, it basically creating game object in runtime to run the script you want

Answer (score 0):

Create an Action Class or an interface deriving from Monobehaviour.

```
public abstract class Action : Monobehaviour {
public virtual void executeAction(); 
...
```

And then create actual actions deriving from that abstract base:

```
public class DestructionAction : Action {
public override void executeAction()
{
    // the actual action code
}
...
```

That way, you can create a lot of different actions. Your "Interaction Code" Script needs a Slot of type "Action" (the abstract base class).

Learn more about Overriding here: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/overriding#5c893d46edbc2a0d28f48954